# How do I remove rows in dataframe A that contains specific number of values from a column of another dataframe B using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, indexing, dataframe

suppose I have a dataframe A as following:

```
item_name
-------------------------
 nike power shoes / 50% off / only today
 nike super t-shirt / adidas / cool sale
 reebok power t-shirt / reebock shoes
```

and another dataframe B is a brand dictionary which is:

---

```
variation  |  original

nike         nike
adidas       adidas
reebok       reebok
reebock      reebok
reeboc       reebok
```

(let's suppose reebock and reeboc as some variations of 'reebok')

my question is that I want to remove rows from dataframe A
that contain **more than 1 brand** based on the dataframe B.
so my desired result is as below:

```
item_name

nike power shoes / 50% off / only today
reebok power t-shirt / reebock shoes
```

you can see that only the row "nike super t-shirt / adidas / cool sale"
has been removed, because we have [nike] and [adidas].
It is important to know this logic is based on the original brand, not the variation part.
Therefore "reebok power t-shirt / reebock shoes" row is not removed since reebok and reebock falls into a unique brand name [reebok].

How can I do this job by pandas?(without using list comprehension)
please give me help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with a mask. It is created by [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) with lambda function. First convert all words to `Series` and then [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `d` and compare [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nunique.html) values:

```
d = df2.set_index('variation')['original']

mask = df1.item_name.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.split()).map(d).nunique() > 1)
print (mask)
0    False
1     True
2    False
Name: item_name, dtype: bool

print (df1[~mask])
                                 item_name
0  nike power shoes / 50% off / only today
2     reebok power t-shirt / reebock shoes
```